# Creating file via R and childprocess in wrong dir

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, child-process

I want to execute some R scripts on my node server. I use child process and it seems to work. My question is:

How can I influence, where the result files are saved? 
Right now, no matter what I do, the results are saved where my server.js is.

But I want to choose myself where to store the results. 
(In my case, I want the results to be where the script has been executed)

How can I do that?

Here`s my code:

This is what I use in my server.js:

```
app.post('/execScript', function (req, res) {
  var childProcess = require('child_process');
  console.log("IM IN SERVER");
  childProcess.exec('Rscript ../app/test.R', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
  })
});
```

this is the ajax call from my js file :

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {project: ""+currentProject+"", script: ""+script+""},
        url: url,
        success: function (content, textStatus) {}
    });
```

Is there even a way to decide where the results should be saved ?

Any help would be great !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass [an `options` object to exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) to specify the *current working directory*:

```
childProcess.exec('Rscript ../app/test.R', {cwd: '/your/path/'}, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  })
```